# Want to track click event in GTM when the element doesnt have css class or id

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I have a product list filter, I want to track event when someone clicks on different 'view type': list/grid/table, screenshot below:
[image]

I was able to track click events using Classes and ID's, but these view elements doesnt have any classes or id, instead it has attribute as "data-type", screenshot below:

[image]

Can someone explain how can I track event when someone clicks on any of these 3 different view types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Click Trigger` with condition `Click Element`

[image]

So to target the first `<a>` element you can use the

CSS Selector :  `a[data-type='list']`

So the other 2 are quite the same

`a[data-type='grid']`

`a[data-type='table']`

---

Or you want to more precisely by narrow the down the range

`div.change-result-view a[data-type='list']`

This mean you only want the `a element with data-type is list` under the `div.change-result-view`

Comment: Do I have to select "Does not match CSS selector"? when I set "Does not match CSS selector" all 3 tags get fired grid, list & table. When I select "Matches CSS selector" none of the tags fire. I also tried "Contains" but none of the tags fire. Dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Oh you should select match css selector. If none of the tag fired. We might need to take a look at your setting screenshot

Comment: [tag screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0mYkx7B.jpeg) and [trigger screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/syMzU5K.jpg) - this is screenshot for grid view. Likewise I had setup tag & trigger for all 3 views. Inside the 'a' tag I have a [child 'i' tag](https://i.imgur.com/kkP8J1g.jpg) with class but it will only track if click happens over the icon, but there is extra space surrounding the icon under the 'a' tag.

Comment: ok got it. The GTM preview might show that it detect the click is on the `<i>` element rather than `<a>`. We could just change the trigger type from `All Click` to `Just Link`. `Just Link` will only focus on `<a>` element even if there are other element on top of it.